# What attributes does d3 transition change?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, d3.js, svg

I am trying to understand what exactly gets transition in d3.

For example

```
var bars = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(my_values)
  .enter()
  .append("rect") // statement before transition
  .attr("x", 10)  // statement before transition
  .transition()   // transition
  .delay(200)
  .duration(1500)
  .attr("height", 10) // statement after transition
  .transition()   // another transition
  .delay(200)
  .duration(1500);
```

1. Does the transition effect any statement before the transition or does the transition effect only statement after the transition
2. How does multiple transition work?

Comment: Transition effect applies to the statement that immediately follows the `.transition()`. When you need to perform a complex transition, it's worth passing an interpolation function instead. See more: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/#interpolation

Comment: This seemed to be a very simple and basic question, but in the process os answering it I found out that it is way more complicated than I thought.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your second question...

> 2. How does multiple transition work?

Is quite simple to answer. Here, the API is clear:

> *transition.transition()*
>
> Returns a new transition on the same selected elements as this transition, scheduled to start when this transition ends.

So, the new transition will start when the previous one finishes, and so on. Let's see it:

```js
var rect = d3.select("svg").append("rect")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 0)
  .style("fill", "black")
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .style("fill", "teal")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

### The interesting question

However, the interesting question here is your first one:

> 1. Does the transition effect any statement before the transition or does the transition effect only statement after the transition?

Well, this is also quite basic: the `transition()` method creates a transition between a starting value and a target value. You have to set the attribute before the transition (the starting value) and after the transition (the target value).

The problem is that attributes not previously set will have a `null` value.

Let's see it: without specifying the `height` of the rectangle, it is `null`:

```js
var rect = d3.select("svg").append("rect");

console.log(rect.attr("height"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Therefore, there is no smooth transition regarding the height if you don't set it before the transition:

```js
var rect = d3.select("svg").append("rect")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("height", 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

And here comes the interesting point: I wrote an answer (now deleted, users with >10k can see it) explaining that the interpolator cannot interpolate from `null` to a given value. However, it **can** interpolate:

```js
var interpolator = d3.interpolateNumber(null, 100);
d3.range(0,1.1,.1).forEach(function(d){
 console.log(interpolator(d))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

So, what is happening here is a bit more complicated. Using `interpolateNumber` we can interpolate from `null` to a given value. Look at this demo, where the `height` was not set:

```js
var rect = d3.select("svg").append("rect")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attrTween("height", function() {
    return d3.interpolateNumber(d3.select(this).attr("height"), 100);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Why the default `transition.attr()` doesn't work when you don't set the attribute before the transition?

After some investigation, it seems to me that `transition()` is converting the numeric target value to a string (like `100` to `"100"`). This is very strange, because the [API explicitly says](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_attr) that...

> ... an interpolator is chosen based on the type of the target value, using the following algorithm:
>
> 1. If value is a number, use `interpolateNumber`.
> 2. If value is a color or a string coercible to a color, use `interpolateRgb`.
> 3. Use `interpolateString`.

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/src/transition/attr.js#L73), look at the last line:

```
export default function(name, value) {
    var fullname = namespace(name),
        i = fullname === "transform" ? interpolateTransform : interpolate;
    return this.attrTween(name, typeof value === "function" 
        ? (fullname.local ? attrFunctionNS : attrFunction)(fullname, i, tweenValue(this, "attr." + name, value)) 
        : value == null ? (fullname.local ? attrRemoveNS : attrRemove)(fullname) 
        : (fullname.local ? attrConstantNS : attrConstant)(fullname, i, value + ""));
        //converting to string here ------------------------------------------^
}
```

As we can see, it's coercing the value to a string. Therefore, the transition will not work because it will use `interpolateString` instead of `interpolateNumber`:

```js
var interpolator = d3.interpolateString(null, "100");
d3.range(0,1.1,.1).forEach(function(d){
 console.log(interpolator(d))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

### Conclusion

`transition()` creates a transition from a starting value to a target value. If the starting value is not set, it will default to `null`. However, as `transition()` uses `interpolateString`, the interpolation will not work properly.

### Update in 18/11/2017

According to Mike Bostock (D3 creator), the source code is correct (and, therefore, the documentation is wrong). As he says in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/pull/67):

> `interpolateString` (or `interpolateRgb`) is the correct behavior here. `interpolateNumber` should never be used for attributes.

The explanation is that values like `"100px"` or `"1.3em"` would not work with `interpolateNumber`. So, again, don't rely on `null` starting values: always set the attribute before and after the `transition()`.

Thanks to @altocumulus for commenting on the GitHub issue.

Comment: You are right, this is a bug. It was ok when the docs were written but was introduced as a side effect of issue *[Coerce value to string for comparison #67](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/pull/67)*. Would you like to comment on that github issue since you stumbled upon it or should I do it?

Comment: @altocumulus You can do it, I'll follow that issue.

Comment: Have you seen the update to the issue? That came as a bit of a surprise! I am fine with that, but it requires yet another update of your answer ;-)

Comment: @altocumulus Yes, I agree with you, the documentation needs to be changed. But, before I update my answer, there is something that I cannot understand: Bostock said *"interpolateNumber should never be used for attributes"*... I'm aware that `getAttribute` returns a string, but what's the problem of using `interpolateNumber`? As you can see in my snippet, it has the nice feature of guaranteeing the transition even if the attribute was not previously set. So, what could possible break if he changed the code according to the documentation?

Comment: Looking at the source it becomes clear, that at some point in time Mike changed his mind on this issue. In `transition/interpolate.js` it is still contained as now unreachable code. So, when v4 came out it was supposed to work this way. I think his main concern now is consistency. The implementation for that interpolator is `d3.interpolateNumber(a, b)`, which *"Returns an interpolator between the two numbers a and b"*. As your starting value will always be a string this might get you into trouble when coercing something like `"100px"` to a number!

Comment: @altocumulus I see your point: I failed to see why `interpolateNumber` would be a problem because I **never** do something like `rect.attr("width", "100px")`, I always do `rect.attr("width", 100)`. Updating my answer (again!)...

Comment: It is always tempting to reduce D3 to SVG... Nonetheless, values as `"100px"` or `"50%"` are more often seen on HTML and are, thus, perfectly valid inputs for these methods.

Comment: Remnants everywhere: there is even a [test](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/test/transition/attr-test.js#L164-L176) for the use of interpolateNumber. It won't break, though, even given the new code.

Answer (score 0):

Transition is one of the important feature in graphical representation of any data with D3JS. Transition is a process of changing from one state to another. This transition can be used in style and attribute methods and this cannot be used in the append and data methods. We can also delay function which is used to pause the flow for selected time and duration function can specify the time of transition.

```
<body>
  <h3>Demo Sample</h3>
  <script>
     d3.select("body")
       .transition()
       .style("background-color", "black")
       .duration(3000);
  </script>
```

Multiple Transition are also possible. First It will execute the first mentioned transition and then followed by next transition. This is the way of working multiple transition in D3JS.