# Can the 'enter' selection for a line graph be animated?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linegraph

I have a line graph that updates very nicely. Until new data enters the question. At that point the 'update' selection animates down as it should but the new data doesn't.

It's hard to explain what's happening, but a gif is worth a thousand words (watch when it transitions *down*):

[image]

I've wrapped the graph in a class with an update and render method. Here's the render method I wrote.

```
render(){
    // Update both Axes
    this.xAxis.transition()
        .call( d3.axisBottom( this.xScale ) );
    this.yAxis.transition()
        .call( this.createYAxis );

    // Exit
    this.line.exit().remove();

    // Enter
    this.line
      .enter().append( 'path' )
        .attr( 'class', 'valueLine' )
        .transition()
        .attr( 'd', this.valueLine );

    // Update
    this.line.transition().attr( 'd', this.valueLine );

    // Allows method chaining
    return this;
}
```

Why doesn't the 'new' data animate in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer

Yes, but you have to define the starting value for the `d` attribute.

#### Long answer

A transition goes from a starting value to a target value. Right now, in your "enter" selection, you have no starting value (that is, before `transition()`) for the `d` attribute:

```
// Enter
this.line
    .enter().append( 'path' )
    .attr( 'class', 'valueLine' )
    .transition()//no 'd' attribute before this line
    .attr( 'd', this.valueLine );
```

Therefore, the `d` attribute for that path is `null` (read more about this [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47340971/5768908)).

Let's see it:

```js
var data = [10, 180, 30, 60, 190, 180, 50, 110, 40, 90, 90];
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .y(function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return i * 60
  });
var path = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data([data])
  .enter()
  .append("path");
  
console.log(path.attr("d"))
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="200"></svg>
```

Here the same code, setting the `d` attribute:

```js
var data = [10, 180, 30, 60, 190, 180, 50, 110, 40, 90, 90];
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .y(function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return i * 60
  });
var path = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data([data])
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", lineGenerator);
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="200"></svg>
```

Back to your question:

You cannot transition the `d` attribute from `null` to your string. It's impossible. There are some possible workarounds, though.

One of them is creating a default `d` attribute before the transition. For instance:

```js
var data = [10, 180, 30, 60, 190, 180, 50, 110, 40, 90, 90];
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .y(function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return i * 60
  });
var path = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data([data])
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M0,100 L600,100")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .attr("d", lineGenerator);
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="200"></svg>
```

But that's a horrible transition! The problem is that the initial `d` attribute has too few points. Because of that, the string interpolator cannot create the interpolation we wish.

So, we can use a custom function, like [this one](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3916621) from Mike Bostock. Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [10, 180, 30, 60, 190, 180, 50, 110, 40, 90, 90];
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .y(function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return i * 60
  });
var path = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data([data])
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M0,100 L600,100")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
    return pathTween(lineGenerator(d), 4, this)()
  });

function pathTween(d1, precision, self) {
  return function() {
    var path0 = self,
      path1 = path0.cloneNode(),
      n0 = path0.getTotalLength(),
      n1 = (path1.setAttribute("d", d1), path1).getTotalLength();

    // Uniform sampling of distance based on specified precision.
    var distances = [0],
      i = 0,
      dt = precision / Math.max(n0, n1);
    while ((i += dt) < 1) distances.push(i);
    distances.push(1);

    // Compute point-interpolators at each distance.
    var points = distances.map(function(t) {
      var p0 = path0.getPointAtLength(t * n0),
        p1 = path1.getPointAtLength(t * n1);
      return d3.interpolate([p0.x, p0.y], [p1.x, p1.y]);
    });

    return function(t) {
      return t < 1 ? "M" + points.map(function(p) {
        return p(t);
      }).join("L") : d1;
    };
  };
}
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="200"></svg>
```

Comment: Perhaps I asked the wrong question, because this doesn't address the issue. I did accept your answer though because it does answer the question I asked. Do you see in the GIF how the line on the right is already there when the transition takes place? And It doesn't move, the left side of the line animates down to meet it? I'm trying to animate the 'right' side of the line so that each side meets one another.

Comment: Also, this won't work in my class anyway because I need the context of the Object to call this.lineGenerator

Comment: Do you know what question I should be asking? Cause I don't quite understand the issue.

Comment: Don't try to transition the enter selection: calculate the whole new line and make the transition in the update selection, using the function I shared. However, for a proper answer, I advise you to create a running code reproducing your GIF, and posting it as a new question (because, as you said, you asked the wrong question here).