# D3: transition path when number of datapoints change

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to animate a path in `D3` (v5) whenever the data updates. Thanks to [this](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_change_data.html) example, I managed to do so with transitions.

However, the behavior is strange when the new data set contains more datapoints than the previous one. When the data is updated, the existing path squeezes to the left of the chart, while the new datapoints are displayed immediately (without animation). This results in a very chaotic and cluttered result, especially if there is more than one line in the chart (the example below is simplified).

[image]

Is there a way to improve this? Ideally the path shouldn't squeeze to the left, but just update the datapoints at their current position. Alternatively, we could animate any 'new' points so they move up from the bottom, which would be softer on the eye, but I haven't found a way to animate ONLY the new points.

```js
// Create 2 datasets
var data1 = [{
    ser1: 0.3,
    ser2: 4
  },
  {
    ser1: 2,
    ser2: 16
  },
  {
    ser1: 3,
    ser2: 8
  },
  {
    ser1: 4,
    ser2: 6
  },
  {
    ser1: 5,
    ser2: 8
  },
  {
    ser1: 6,
    ser2: 10
  },
  {
    ser1: 7,
    ser2: 6
  }
];

var data2 = [{
    ser1: 1,
    ser2: 7
  },
  {
    ser1: 4,
    ser2: 1
  },
  {
    ser1: 6,
    ser2: 8
  }
];

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Initialise a X axis:
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .attr("class", "myXaxis")

// Initialize an Y axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "myYaxis")

// Create a function that takes a dataset as input and update the plot:
function update(data) {

  // Create the X axis:
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.ser1
  })]);
  svg.selectAll(".myXaxis").transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .call(xAxis);

  // create the Y axis
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.ser2
  })]);
  svg.selectAll(".myYaxis")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .call(yAxis);

  // Create a update selection: bind to the new data
  var u = svg.selectAll(".lineTest")
    .data([data], function(d) {
      return d.ser1
    });

  // Updata the line
  u
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "lineTest")
    .merge(u)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("d", d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.ser1);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.ser2);
      })
      .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX))
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2.5)
}

// At the beginning, I run the update function on the first dataset:
update(data1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="update(data1)">Dataset 1</button>
<button onclick="update(data2)">Dataset 2</button>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Comment: @Gerardo There has to be yet another dupe target which is an even better fit... I can clearly picture it in mind's eye: it comes with an animated GIF like this post. I am not able to find it, though.

Comment: @altocumulus maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47363028/5768908)?  Probably not, because it's not an exact dupe.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Nah! It showed the same bending and twisting like this one.