# How do I fix this botched transition resulting from missing data in my D3.js line chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, transition, linechart

I have a D3.js line chart that updates when the user chooses a new country. Overall I'm satisfied with the way my chart updates and it looks very clean when two conditions are met:

1. There is no missing data for either country
2. Country one has no missing data but country two has missing data.

Here is the problem scenario: country one has missing data but country two has no missing data.

If country one has missing data on the left, when the chart updates, the new segments of the line get appended on the right side (usually on top of the existing segments of the line) and then gradually slide over to the left. It's a very ugly transition and words might not suffice so here are a few pictures.

**Country One: Missing data on left**

[image: Starting Point]

**Transition to Country Two (which has no missing data)**

[image: Mid-transition]

**Country Two: No missing data**

[image: Transition Complete]

I have a hunch about the source of the problem and how I might be able to fix it.

**A potential solution?**

This line chart by Mike Bostock is interesting. It has missing data but it uses linear interpolation to fill in the gaps. Would I be able to solve my problem by filling in the gaps like this? I tried implementing this solution but I just can't get the second line for the missing data to appear.

https://observablehq.com/@d3/line-with-missing-data

**The Code for my Line Chart**

I have two separate functions for my line chart. The render function initializes the chart and then I have to use the update function to transition to new data. I know that's a bit weird but I'm relatively inexperienced with D3.js and I can't get it to work with one function. For the That is another potential problem in and of itself, but I don't think it's causing the botched transition, is it?

For the sake of brevity, I only included the parts where the line gets appended and where it gets updated.

```
function render(url){

    d3.json(url).then(function (data) {

        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.Year = +d.Year;
            d.Value = +d.Value / 1000;
        });
...
...
omitted code
...
...

   svg.append("path")
       .datum(data)
       .attr('id','mainline')
       .attr("fill", "none")
       .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
       .attr("stroke-width", 3)
       .attr("d", d3.line()
           .defined(d => !isNaN(d.Value))
           .x(function (d) {
               return x(d.Year)
           })
           .y(function (d) {
               return y(d.Value)
           })
       );
}





function update(url) {

    //Reading in new data and updating values
    d3.json(url).then(function (data) {

        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.Year = +d.Year;
            d.Value = +d.Value / 1000;
        });
...
...
omitted code
...
...

   var lines = svg.selectAll("#mainline").datum(data).attr("class","line");

   lines.transition().ease(d3.easeLinear).duration(1500)
       .attr("d", d3.line()
           .defined(d => !isNaN(d.Value))
           .x(function (d) {
               return x(d.Year)
           })
           .y(function (d) {
               return y(d.Value)
           })
       );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try the `pathTween` function I talk about here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47363793/5768908

Comment: That solved it for me! My transition looks beautiful now thanks to you.